# Powershell Continuations (>>) Broken In ISE But Not Normal Prompt

Tags: powershell

I've been working on this for 2 hours and I'm pulling my hair out. I was working in ISE on my profile script. I don't know if it's relevant but I was trying to store some commands in a variable and execute them later. Anyway I started getting a weird error when trying to create a here-string:

> PS > $foo = @"

Ordinarily I would expect

> >>

to follow, but instead I get this message:

> PS C:\Users\lamartin> @"
>   The string is missing the terminator: "@.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

To make a long story short I have discovered that ALL my multi-line commands are broken, but only in ISE:

> PS > gci |
>
> An empty pipe element is not allowed.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
>
> PS > gci |% {
>
> Missing closing '}' in statement block.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

I removed all profiles and all modules. I verified there was nothing extra being loaded (that I could find). Here is something interesting I did find out. It turns out that Powershell actually ALWAYS errors whenever you do a continuation. It just hides it:

http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/371321/benign-errors-for-missing-closing-are-left-in-the-error-variable

And sure enough if I type in one of the above commands in a regular window, while it works silently, if I later go back and look at the $error object there is an identical error. So basically ISE has decided to stop supressing these errors. I looked at all the settings I could think of $WarningPreference $ErrorActionPreference, etc but they are the same in ISE and normal console.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update**
Wow I feel stupid. Apparently this is expected behavior. I could have SWORN that it was behaving differently just a little bit earlier. I guess I was tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell ISE, you can run a multiline command in the Command Pane. Press SHIFT+ENTER to enter each line of a multiline command, and press ENTER after the last line to execute the multiline command. You can find this in [How to Use the Console Pane in the Windows PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/how-to-use-the-console-pane-in-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Wow you're right. I knew about the SHIFT+ENTER, but I thought line continuation worked the same in ISE as it does in the console. I feel stupid having worked on this for hours for no reason. Thanks JPBlanc.

Comment: unfortunately, the link is broken

Comment: Thanks, the link is repaired now.